# Verify JWT Token in angular

Tags: python, angular, django-rest-framework, jwt

My application backend runs on Django Rest Framework and and frontend on Angular.

I'm already using JWT for authentication and that works fine.

My requirement is to call a specific API (Not authentication related), which gets me some details in plain text. I don't want it in plain text, So I was thinking I would create a JWT Token and send it in response and decode it in frontend using the secret key.

I achieved the decoding part using jwt-decode without the secret. My concern is, if an attacker intercepts my response and modifies the token, How do I tackle that situation?

This is how I decoded the token in angular

```
try {
  decoded = jwt_decode(token);
  return decoded;
} catch (Error) {
  return null;
}
```

Is there a way I could verify/decode my token with secret in Angular? something like:

```
data = jwt.decode(encoded_token, 'SECRET_KEY', algorithms=['algo']) # Python Code
```

Kindly guide me here. If there are any other methods to achieve what I Want please let me know

Comment: eager to know why jwt? even jwts are not encrypted bydefault. you can use https or other encryption methods to encrypt api response.

Comment: @HPSingh I'm open to that, can u point me to an article explaining the implementation of the same in python?

Comment: I don't have any perticular article link and knowledge about python, but angular/node comes with cryptoJS so you can decrypt it. maybe these links help.
encryption: https://appdividend.com/2020/06/16/pycrypto-example-encryption-and-decryption-in-python/
decryption: https://morioh.com/p/bbe2434acaa9

Comment: @HPSingh Angular runs in the browser, nodejs is backend. They use different crypto APIs. Also, decrypting things in the browser doesn't make much sense, as it would mean that anyone has access to your private key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't want it in plain text, So I was thinking I would create a JWT Token and send it in response and decode it in frontend using the secret key.

A JWT token is usually plain-text. There are two types of JWTs - JWS (signed JWTs) and JWE (encrypted JWTs). The latter has the content encrypted, so no one can read it unless they have the key for decryption. Encryption is hard to configure and manage, though, so JWEs are not used very often. You need a really strong reason to be using JWEs. Signed JWTs (JWS) are more common. In fact, when people use the term JWT, they usually mean JWS. A signed JWT is integrity-protected. Using the signature you can verify that the JWT hasn't been changed by an attacker, but they are plain-text. Anyone can read the content of the JWT, they just can't modify it.

Also remember that an Angular app has all of its code available to users, which means it can't hold any secrets. If you put a secret in your Angular app, then anyone will be able to read that secret and use it to decrypt your JWEs, or forge new JWSs, if you're using symmetric signing (e.g. the HS256 algorithm).

> I achieved the decoding part using jwt-decode without the secret. My concern is, if an attacker intercepts my response and modifies the token, How do I tackle that situation?

If you're concerned about a Man-in-the-middle attack, so that someone will modify the response from your server, then all you need is an HTTPS connection. If you connect to your API using HTTPS, then you're sure that no one modified the response, nor read it.

If you're concerned that your response will get modified after HTTPS is terminated (e.g. a malicious code running in the browser), then you can use JWS to ensure the integrity of the response. You just have to remember to use asymmetric signing, so that the Angular app only keeps the public key.

I don't know which library for JWTs are you using in Angular, but I think all of them are capable of verifying signatures, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation. This is how i create the token in my django backend - token = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret', algorithm='HS256'). Also, the package I use to create the token is https://pypi.org/project/jwt/

Comment: This is the python package. What package in the angular code are you using? Also, as I mentioned before, there is no point in using a JWT signed with HS256 in Angular. Everyone will have access to your secret and they will be able to issue their own JWTs, as this is symmetric signing. You would have to use RS256, PS256, or ES256. Your python app should use a private key, and Angular the corresponding public key.

Comment: Understood. I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode in angular. I have been looking for a resource that helps me in the implementation of asymmetric signing. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: As what you're trying to achieve is non-standard, it will probably be hard to find tutorials that show exactly that approach. What you need, though, is to learn how to create an rsa key pair (you can easily Google that). Then you can issue and validate tokens the same way you do it now, but with proper key and algorithm. E.g. in Python `token = jwt.encode(payload, privateKey, algorithm='RS256')`. In Angular you will use the public key to verify the JWT.

Comment: BTW, the jwt-decode lib can't verify signatures. You can use this library to verify JWTs in the browser: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@curity/jwt-validation